# JTabbedPane: call tabs from other classes

Tags: java, jtabbedpane

That's the problem: I built a JTappedPane application. For every tab I made a separate class:

**MainFrame**

```
public MainFrame () {
    StartTab startTab = new StartTab();
    KundeTab kundeTab = new KundeTab();
    ProjektTab projektTab = new ProjektTab();
    StimmzettelTab stimmzettelTab = new StimmzettelTab();
    ExportTab exportTab = new ExportTab();

    JTabbedPane jtp = new JTabbedPane();
    jtp.addTab("xxx",startTab);
    jtp.addTab("xxx",kundeTab);
    jtp.addTab("xxx",projektTab);
    jtp.addTab("xxx",stimmzettelTab);
    jtp.addTab("xxx",exportTab);

    frame.getContentPane().add(jtp);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Now I want to use a button in StartTab to call KundeTab

**Button in StartTab**

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent s) {
      s.getActionCommand();

      // How can i switch to Tab xy?

      System.out.println("Switch Tab");
    }
});
```

In my first JTappedPane project I build the gui completely in one class. In this case I could use jtp.***setSelectedIndex(int)*** with the Int of the tab. But this doesn't work with multiple classes for tabs.

Hope you can help me! I'm searching the whole day for a solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may retrieve the successive parents of the clicked `Component` (`JButton` here), until you find the `JTabbedPane` :

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent s) {
        s.getActionCommand();

        Component source = (Component) s.getSource();

        Container parent = source.getParent();// will give the container of the button

        do {

            parent = parent.getParent();

        } while (!(parent instanceof JTabbedPane));

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = (JTabbedPane)parent;

        // How can i switch to Tab xy?
        tabbedPane.setSelectedIndex(xyIndex);

        System.out.println("Switch Tab");
    }
});
```